# How to load some JavaScript file in node-mongodb-native?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I use node-mongodb-native in my project and I need to load some JavaScript file with my custom functions like in the following [tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/load/)

My code for connecting to database looks like the following:

```
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server('localhost', 27017, {
        socketOptions: {keepAlive: 1}
        , auto_reconnect: true
        , poolSize: 10
    }),
{
    native_parser: true
    , w:1
});

mongoClient.open(function (err, mongoClient) {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    var db = mongoClient.db('test');

    console.log('Database connect success!');

    // ... application code
});
```

I need to load underscore.js file into mongodb to be possible use it functions inside server-side functions saved by using `db.system.js.save`

I can't find a way of doing that. Please help me.

Comment: The node.js equivalent would be to use `require`.

Comment: @xShirase I've added code example but I don't understand how could I load `myscript.js` into the mongodb?

Comment: @JohnnyHK I need to load `myscript.js` into mongodb

Comment: What do you mean by "load `myscript.js` into mongodb"?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying execute server-side functions via `db.eval( "echoFunction( 'test' )" )` and need access to `myscript.js` functions

Comment: When I say "load `myscript.js` into mongodb" I mean to load and run a JavaScript file into the current shell environment. Like as the following http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/load/

Comment: Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I think so, but I don't know a way to do what you're looking for.

Comment: I it possible to provide js file into connection config?

Comment: I'm looking for something like the following http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#execute-a-javascript-file